# LoadError: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I'm using **Ruby 2.2.2** with **Rails 4.2**
when i try to run any rake task i have this error message
why is that? and what can i do?

- Ruby 2.2.2
- Rails 4.2
- rbenv
- Arch Linux
- PostgreSQL database

**error message**

`` rake aborted!
LoadError: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/adham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/adham/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/home/code/kahareb/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/code/kahareb/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace) ``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error message while trying to run `rails console` after last Arch Linux update, and I solved it reinstalling ruby (using [rvm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RVM)). Try the following:

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.2.2
```

Comment: This is to adapt to your current ruby version. You may use `rvm info` to figure that out...

Comment: thanks dude i switched to `rvm` and it's working fine now @olivao